# How to define or use karate-config.js in standalone jar?

Tags: cucumber, dsl, karate

I see with the standalone jar, you can supply karate.env with `-e` or `--env` but can you also specify anything to define karate-config.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be looked for in the "root" folder by default.

To over-ride, this happens to be a little different, a Java System property:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#karate-configjs

But I recommend setting a classpath, and karate should look for it there. If not, please do consider contributing or updating the docs.